# Running on MonoDevelop SignalR ChatHub Undefined

Tags: c#, mono, signalr

I'm trying to setup a `SignalR` project using `Monodevelop`. I got the `SignalR` packages installed through `Nuget` and everything compiles, but I keep getting `cannot read property of undefined` when I hit my page.

I can't figure out what I'm missing, and at this point I think I might be missing a configuration file.

Here's what I have:

```
// the view
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
    <script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
    <script>
        $(function () {
            // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.  
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.

            console.log(chat);

            chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
                // Add the message to the page. 

                console.log('here');

                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name) 
                    + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message) + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
        // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
        function htmlEncode(value) {
            var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
            return encodedValue;
        }
    </script>
}
```

It seems that `~/signalr/hubs` does not 404 but when I preview the context in chrome, there's nothing there. It's an empty file, which might be the root cause of everything.

Here is the startup file. I put a breakpoint the `configuration` method and it does hit that code.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup ()
        {
        }

        public void Configuration (IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR ();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the hub:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace SignalRChat
{
    [HubName("chatHub")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send (string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage (name, message);
        }

        public ChatHub ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Ran this code on Visual Studios on an IIS server and things work. I think this might be a specific issue with `mono`. I added the tag.

Comment: Which version of Mono are you using? (`mono --version`)

Comment: I am using version `4.2.3`

Comment: Which SignalR DLLs are in your executing folder? (I have to use both `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.dll` and `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll`)

Comment: I have both `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core.Dll`, `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb.dll` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like SignalR only works when self-hosting.

Found the two links. I haven't tried yet, but this is probably the solution.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1924358.aspx?Signalr+on+mono
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15267.running-signalr-on-mono.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to register your ChatHub class with SignalR. Here's how I usually do it:

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(ChatHub), () =>
    {
        ChatHub hub = new ChatHub();
        return hub;
    });

    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

After you have done this the `~/signalr/hubs` should contain what you need

Comment: Where do you place that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have made that more clear. I've updated the code to show where I put it.

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have to explicitly add my hubs to the web server.  It was my understanding that being derived from Hub and calling MapSignalR() would do that.  But I can tell you, mine has been working for 2 years and I don't call Register() on my hub anywhere, nor create an instance of it anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this did not resolve the issue and "~/signalr/hubs" is still an empty file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but mine has an unaltered HubConfiguation:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HubConfiguration config = new HubConfiguration();
    config.EnableJSONP = true;
    app.MapSignalR(config);
}
```

You can see more about my signature here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262337/1322383

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, this did not solve the issue. The auto generated `~/signalr/hubs` is still blank